# How To Configure D-Link Wifi Router To Connect Between Pc Local (Wamp) Server And Android Device

Tags: wireless-networking, android, wamp

I buy a Wifi Router and setup.
All is running good, but just 3 issues:

Issue No 1. On my pc (Local server) I edit host file like below:

```
127.0.0.1       example.com
```

so, on my browser, if I enter example.com it redirects to my wamp server :) but the issue is, when I enter http://example.com on my tablets it don't work. (Page cant be displayed message shows) but if I enter ip address it works like charm. So, is there any way to use site name instead of ip address on tables too?

Issue No 2. If I connect my internet cable (Ethernet cable) on router, tablets can also access internet. (Yes it is simple/general). But what I want is, only pc/laptop that are connected thought router LAN port can only access internet, but through wifi it must not have access to internet. Is that possible? I hope so. If so then how?

Why I need these, because I have limited speed internet connection. And my tablets users can misuse this :( thus affect my computer internet works/speed.

Issue No 3:
My home pc is windows XP SP3. I test on my home pc and it works as it should :). But on my shop I have windows 7 sp1. I can't connect if windows firewall is on. I can only connect if I disable windows firewall. But disabling firewall is not a good practice. I even tried to add inbound rules for TCP port 80 and 8080 (when 80 fails I tried with 8080). But none of them works. It only works if I turn off windows firewall.

So, my question is, what should I do to make it works without disabling windows firewall?

thanks in advance..

best regards

Comment: Of course it's possible, that's what computer networks are for.  :)  But as-is this question is WAAAY too vague, and giving you exact steps  to accomplish you stat (too broad) goals would be impossible.  Short answer:   1) Buy router, 2) Set up network, 3) Profit.   When you get stuck with specific problems, and have specific questions, come back. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to add comment to the post above so I'll try to answer here..

Issue 1 : using hosts file to redirect a domain only works on the computer itself.. There's no other way (in my knowledge) to access your server instead of entering its IP address.

Issue 2 : In my opinion you can use several ways to restrict internet access.
No 1: You can change the gateway in DHCP settings to other IP address. Default gateway is the router itself, so changing to other IP will make the connection "Limited"
No 2: You can limit the bandwidth to the lowest value for each device that connects to your router.

Hope this solution works you and CMIIW~